# Adding interviewer on LinkedIn after taking other job

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer

There were two job vacancies in particular that appealed to me – 'Job A' and 'Job B'

I had an interview for Job A, and then the next day I had a telephone interview with Job B, the manager then said about us having a proper interview next week.

The day after that, I got offered Job A.

I plan to go with Job A as I feel it will be the better option of the two, but I feel it's a shame about the timing. As I would have liked to consider the 'Job B' company perhaps several years down the line if I wanted to move on from Job A.

I am therefore planning on turning down Job B... but I'm tempted to say to the manager that I'll connect on LinkedIn, that way, maybe in years to come, I could then get in touch with him about possibly working there if they have a vacancy.

Might this be a bad idea the fact I'm already thinking about my next job when I haven't even started this one yet?

Comment: Just send a connection invitation. No dialog, comments, or explanation is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s fine to connect with any business contact on LinkedIn and you don’t need a big spiel as to why.  As a hiring manager I have prospective employees, ones in the process, and ones who did and did not get offers connect with me, and I’m happy to accept if they were not rank psychos.

Feel free and add a brief note “While it didn’t work out right now I enjoyed speaking with you and learning about X Corp and would like to connect.” Hiring managers would also live further recommendations from you on people that might be a fit for what they’re hiring for, so feel free and refer if you really want to be remembers and on their good list.